# Вводное сочетание "по данным..."

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Хотелось бы понять на примере из грамоты, когда же таки нужно ставить запятую.

..."вводные сочетания  «по данным (кого-либо, чего-либо, чьим-либо)» обособляются".

Пример:

По данным комендатуры, фамилия капитана – Николаев, лейтенанта – Сенцов.

Не смешивать с употреблением в роли членов предложения.

Пример:

По данным разведки мы знали об этом. Л. Брежнев, Малая земля.

В чём разница в этих примерах? Почему второе – члены предложения, а первое – вводное сочетание?

Спасибо.

Comment: Дурацкий пример у Грамоты, оно не по-русски звучит. Надо так: *Мы знали об этом по данным разведки.*

Comment: А кому надо именно так? Лично вам? :))  Актуальное членение предложения меняет смысл сказанного и соответствует контексту.  (1) Откуда мы это знали? – Мы знали об этом по данным разведки.  (2)  По данным разведки мы знали об этом. – Информация была уже известна  по данным разведки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в том, что *данные разведки* могут относиться либо к утверждению в целом (то есть фактически получается два отдельных утверждения, разделяемые запятой), либо же служить обстоятельством описываемой ситуации (одно утверждение, нет запятой).

```
По данным разведки, мы знали об этом =  Данные разведки говорят что, мы знали об этом.

По данным разведки мы знали об этом =  Мы знали об этом на основании данных разведки.
```

В случае глагола *быть* получаем одно и то же. Поэтому запятая опциональна.

```
По данным разведки, он был русским =  Данные разведки говорят что, он был русский.

По данным разведки он был русский =  Он был русский на основании данных разведки.
```

Comment: Совершенно с вами согласен. Хотел писать примерно то же самое.

Только второй пример в первой рамке я упростил бы, просто изменив порядок слов: «Мы знали об этом по данным разведки». Тогда словосочетание представляет собой простое обстоятельство с элементами модальности, отвечающее на вопрос «откуда?» и не имеющее никаких причин для обособления.

Comment: Добавлю, что в официально-деловом стиле запятая чаще всего будет стоять вне зависимости от тонкостей. :) Она структурирует предложение, сразу превращает вводное сочетание в модальное.

Comment: Обстоятельство может обособляться по разным причинам,  модальность для этого не является обязательной. МОДАЛЬНОСТЬ, -и; ж. [от лат. modus - наклонение] 1. Лог. Категория, выражающая отношение говорящего к содержанию высказывания с точки зрения его возможности, невозможности, случайности или необходимости.  Указание на источник сообщения  имеет значение модальности?

Comment: В каких случаях обстоятельство, не выраженное придаточным предложением, оборотом или вводным словом/конструкцией (т. е. ситуациях, где запятые ставятся по другим причинам), может обособляться?

Comment: Это называется актуализацией (выделением) оборота с целью придания ему особой значимости или, напротив, указания на дополнительный характер сообщения.

Comment: Пожалуй, я подобрал не то слово. Как называется вводная конструкция, указывающая на источник информации? «По его словам», «по версии следствия» и т. д.? И не редактируйте, пожалуйста, настолько фундаментально свой комментарий после написания.

Comment: Откуда такие ограничения?  Я просто ищу более подходящую форму для сказанного.  И вы, пожалуйста, выбирайте слова точно по их смыслу.

Answer (score 2):

!. ***По данным комендатуры**, фамилия капитана – Николаев, лейтенанта – Сенцов.* Это сложное предложение (БСП), вводное сочетание выделяется интонационно и является общим для обоих предложений.

Кроме того, в каждом предложении ставится тире, которое нужно обозначить паузой.  Таки образом, интонационная структура не такая простая, как во втором предложении.

2.***По данным разведки** мы знали об этом.*  Это простое нераспространенное предложение, обстоятельство в начале предложения не обособляется (причем его довольно сложно обособить).

Соответственно, в предложениях разной структуры мы имеем **разное решение.** И заодно **философский вывод:** нет в природе ничего абсолютно одинакового, иначе невозможно было бы сделать выбор.

Для справок: ОПЦИЯ, ж. [англ. option от лат. optio (optiōnis) - выбор, усмотрение].

И запятая в двух приведенных предложениях не опциональна.

Comment: И какой же это вид обстоятельства из 9-ти возможных: места, времени, причины, цели, характеристики действия, меры, условия, уступки, следствия?

Comment: На самом деле ряд обстоятельств никто не ограничивает (информацию об этом можно найти в источниках). Вы просто назвали самые известные.  Ну давайте назовем его обстоятельством соответствия. Вам нравится? По-моему, красивое и вполне подходящее название. Но вы можете выбрать другое.:))

Comment: Что значит, никто не ограничивает? Это официальная терминология, которая выстроена и согласована с окружающими. Единственный способ определить, что что-то является обстоятельством — это определить соответствие этого с одним из девяти видов обстоятельств. Нельзя придумывать свои виды обстоятельства, как, например, нельзя придумывать свои части речи. Назвать сочетание из вопроса обстоятельством соответствия есть то же самое, что и назвать слово ‟хлеб” обстоятельством мучных изделий, а слово ‟вагина” — обстоятельством репродуктивных органов.

Comment: Вы меня не перестаете удивлять своими суждениями. Ну прочитайте хотя вот это:  "Виды обстоятельств. Обстоятельства принято делить по значению. Поскольку семантически обстоятельства очень разнообразны, то и видов обстоятельств выделяют много.  В этой статье, к примеру,  выделено 12 обстоятельств https://studopedia.ru/3_79396_obstoyatelstvo-vidi-obstoyatelstv-i-sposobi-ih-virazheniya.html

Comment: Там те же 9, только некоторые из них разбиты на два вида. Обстоятельства меры и степени разбиты на 2 вида, хотя их обычно объединяют в один вид. Обстоятельства места разбиты на место и обстановка, хотя обычно такие ситуации покрывает просто обстоятельство места. Добавлено еще каким-то лингвополеном модальные. В первом примере: ‟День действительно выдался солнечным” — ‟солнечным” является сказуемым. ЛОЛ! Второй пример: ‟Обыкновенно я ездил в пером классе” — не имеет смысла.  Если предположить, что до инсульта человек хотел написать: ‟Я ездил в школу обыкновенно”, то ‟обыкновенно” —

Comment: обстоятельство характеристики действия. В итоге, все те же самые виды + один вид добавлен каким-то лингвополеном.

Comment: Если имеется ввиду, что ‟действительно” — это ‟модальное” обстоятельство, то на самом деле ‟действительно” является частицей. Если до инсульта человек хотел написать: ‟Обычно я ездил в первом классе”, то ‟обычно” является обстоятельством времени и частоты.

Comment: Ну что же, желаю вам успехов в изучении данной темы.  Вы уж наведите там порядок. Из словаря: ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО. I. нареч. В действительности, подлинно, в самом деле. Он д. очень устал. II. вводн. сл. Подтверждает чью-л. мысль, выражает уверенность в чём-л. На этот раз, д., он прав. III. частица. Употр. для выражения утверждения; да, верно. Он так сказал? - Д.   Кстати, тут у нас как раз проводится семинар по частицам и наречиям, но как-то все мыслят по-разному,  и вопрос пока не решен.

Comment: Речь, конечно же, идет о ‟действительно” в данном предложении. В данном предложении слово ‟действительно” является частицей.

Comment: А вы можете назвать принципиальное различие между частицей и наречием (очень кратко, в двух словах).

Comment: В общем конечно же не могу, так как любая классификация это 60 процентов отчетливого распределения по классам, 20 процентов исходя из тонких соображений и 20 процентов, которые могут быть только результатов условностей между людьми или решениями исходя из удобства. Можно говорить только о конкретной частице или наречии и почему они распределены по тем или иным классам.

Comment: А я вот считаю, что каждая часть речи должна определяться по строгим общепринятым КРИТЕРИЯМ, а иначе все рассуждения – это лишь пустые разговоры досужих людей ни о чем.  Примеров подобных дискуссий здесь достаточно – каждый слышит только себя и разговаривает сам с собой.

Comment: Часть речи, например, наречие состоит из подклассов: места, времени, причины, цели, характеристики действия, меры и степени. И это не говоря уже о местоименных. Нельзя дать какое-то отчеилитивое определение для наречия в целом, так как оно будет очень общим и бесполезным. Можно говорить только о отчетливых характеристиках подклассов наречий. Нельзя говорить о наречиях вообще, но можно говорить о, например, наречиях характеристики действия.

Comment: Возьмите любой вузовский учебник «Морфология современного русского языка». Там все части речи расписаны по статьям.1. Категориальное значение (определение). 2.  Морфологические признаки. 3. Синтаксическая функция и т.д. Да и школьный разбор делается так же.  Вот и сравнивайте частицу и наречие по этим пунктам.

Answer (score 1):

Отсутствие запятой может быть, только если автор задумал это предложение как сумбурно-разговорную речь с непрямым порядком слов, где предложение: ‟Мы знали об этом по данным разведки” — произносится задом наперед. Это либо такого рода речь, либо ошибка. В любом случае человек из Грамоты заслуживает пинка.